# How to put text at rightmost position of an underline?

Tags: positioning, underline

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0cm,top=0.2cm,bottom=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
%\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Biolinum O}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Akaash}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\ListItem}[1]{\underline{\makebox[5cm][l]{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা,রিক্সা ভাড়া}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা,রিক্সা ভাড়া}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা,রিক্সা ভাড়া}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\\

\vspace{2cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা,রিক্সা ভাড়া}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা,রিক্সা ভাড়া}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা,রিক্সা ভাড়া}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\\

\vspace{2cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা,রিক্সা ভাড়া}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা,রিক্সা ভাড়া}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা,রিক্সা ভাড়া}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

I want to add text "40 taka" in the last line(রিক্সা ভাড়া) of the list in the right side of the underline.

Comment: Instead of `\makebox[5cm][l]{#1}` try `\makebox[5cm][r]{#1}`.  The `l` means left alignment and the `r` is for right alignment.  Also, it would be helpful if you eliminate the unnecessary lines in this so one can focus on the just the issue at hand.  Alternatively, use `\newcommand{\ListItem}[2]{\underline{\makebox[5cm][r]{#1\hfill#2}}}`

Comment: If you just want to do exactly what you say, you could simply use `{রিক্সা ভাড়া \hfill 40 taka}` as the last item in the list.

Comment: @AlanMunn yes your solution is right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least for the simple case you describe, it's sufficient to add `\hfill 40 taka` to the last element of each list.

```
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা,রিক্সা ভাড়া\hfill 40 taka}
```

[image: partial output of code]